# How can I determine if a network switch has sufficient bandwidth to support PC to PC transfers at the same time as internet access?

Tags: router, home-networking, switch

I have a problem with a switch that will allow high traffic between two PCs yet this transfer interferes​ with a third that wants to get through the switch to a router  and on to the internet. As a result I need a switch that knows to route traffic to specific ports instead of broadcasting all traffic to all ports.

All 3 PCs are on the same subnet.

Imagine that I want to keep Netflix flowing even if two other computers on the same subnet are transferring files between their windows shares.

Originally I bought a [Cisco/Linksys SE1500 "switch"](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B006C2DV5G)
 on Amazon and found that the traffic from the two PCs was blocking all the other ports.

Back when I used to buy switches they kept a MAC address table in memory and switched traffic to where it should go.

Maybe the problem has to do with the capacity of the backplane of the cheap switch that was causing the blocking.  I don't really understand how to shop for what I want in this price range.

How can I determine whether a switch I am looking at online will have the capacity I need?

Comment: Maybe that el cheapo $12 10/100 switch just doesn't have the backplane bandwidth to handle more than 100Mbps of traffic at a time. I've been using Netgear GS108 and GS608 GigE switches for years and have no real complaints.

Comment: @SDsolar I've removed the comment chaff and hopefully tried to clarify your question slightly.

Comment: You already mentioned the term and specification you need: The backplane capacity. You could always try to ask the manufacturer for those details if they're not available. Other than that you probably have to rely on Feedback from other users of the product. There is no other metric than the backplane capacity that will help you in this case. A switch should never broadcast all traffic to all ports. If it was it's either defect or a hub.

Comment: You are right, @Seth.  Turns out that feedback from others was just what the doctor ordered.   And thank you, Mokubai.  I am very happy with the Netgear GS108E.

Comment: Ah ha.  I finally found a couple of units on Amazon that list their bandwidth capability.  I think I will try the T-Link one just to see if there is a difference.  I am still able to saturate the Netgear unit running backups between systems.  They have a 16-port model and an 8-port model, (in the same listing) and the listed backplane capacity is different between them.    It would be nice to have this problem completely go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the Netgear GS108E and lo and behold, the problem is solved.

This is a whole different world now.  Much more like I had in mind.

Thank you all for the guidance, especially @Mokubai.

Comment: This thing is much more like the commercial units I used to buy.  Performance is excellent.  Thank you again for the help.